Get high res icon image as UIImage in iOS 18
Before iOS 18, I have the following code that works well:
    let icons = Bundle.main.infoDictionary!["CFBundleIcons"] as! [String: Any]
    let primaryIcon = icons["CFBundlePrimaryIcon"] as! [String: Any]
    let iconName = primaryIcon["CFBundleIconName"] as! String
    return UIImage(named: iconName)!

The iconName is "AppIcon", and it returns the 1024x1024 image. Now using iOS 18 base SDK, UIImage(named: iconName) is nil, causing a crash in my app.
More details:

If I build using base SDK iOS 17, it runs fine on both iOS 17 and iOS 18.
If I build using base SDK iOS 18 (with deployment target iOS 17), it crashes on both iOS 17 and iOS 18.

I have tried the answers from How to get UIImage of AppIcon?, but the result isn't as good. Specifically, the following code that uses CFBundleIconFiles instead of CFBundleIconName:
    let icons = Bundle.main.infoDictionary!["CFBundleIcons"] as! [String: Any]
    let primaryIcon = icons["CFBundlePrimaryIcon"] as! [String: Any]
    let iconFiles = primaryIcon["CFBundleIconFiles"] as! [String]
    return UIImage(named: iconFiles[0])!

The iconFiles[0] returns AppIcon60x60, which uses AppIcon60x60@2x.png in main bundle which is 120x120, a lot lower than 1024x1024.
I have done the following research:

In my app setup, I use asset catelog (Assets.xcassets -> AppIcon), with a image file called icon1024.png that is 1024x1024.

In General tab of the target setting, I set AppIcon as the app icon.

in the resulting product (.app file), I see 3 related files:



AppIcon60x60@2x.png
AppIcon76x76@2x~ipad.png
Assets.car

Then I use "Asset Catelog Tinker" app to inspect Assets.car, I got a single file icon1024.png.
I tried building with both iOS 17 and iOS 18, and got the same .app folder structure.
This means that when building with base SDK iOS 17, when calling UIImage(named: "AppIcon"), it somehow magically loads Assets.car/icon1024.png file. However, if I do UIImage(named: "icon1024"), or UIImage(named: "icon1024.png"), or UIImage(named: "Assets.car/icon1024.png") or UIImage(named: "Assets.car/icon1024.png"), it returns nil.
I don't know why I worked before (anyone knows?), but this doesn't work anymore when building for iOS 18. So what should I do?

Since ios18 is still beta, you should file beta feedback

@Paulw11 are there other ways to access the high resolution app icon file?

That was admittedly an interesting challenge.
Indeed, app icons seem to be packaged in the car file with no way to access them in runtime.
It also appears that we have only some small sized freestanding icons in the bundle... but
Looking through the compiler options I've found this setting:
ASSETCATALOG_COMPILER_STANDALONE_ICON_BEHAVIOR
which can be found in:
Build Settings > Asset Catalog Compiler - Options > Standalone Icon File Behavior
and it seems to enable pretty much what we want:

Controls whether loose PNG or ICNS files are created for the primary app icon, in addition to including the content in the Assets.car file. By default, a small subset of sizes are included as loose files, allowing external management tools to display a representative icon without reading the CAR file. This can be set to 'all' or 'none' to include more or fewer icon sizes as loose files.


So after setting this to all we are golden but keep in mind that it only seems to work (I did all the testing) if you include at least one scheme-specific variant (for lack of a better term).
For example, if you only set the Any Appearance slot it doesn't include a copy of the 1024 icon.
So you want something like this:

and now finally we get the glorious 1024 icon freestanding in the bundle:

which of course you can load either with your existing code (since the icons are now included in CFBundleIcons/CFBundleIconFiles) or via UIImage(named: "AppIcon1024x1024") directly or by using any other Bundle related API.
Oh, by the way there is one more flag (Include All App Icon Assets - ASSETCATALOG_COMPILER_INCLUDE_ALL_APPICON_ASSETS) that exposes the alternative icons (i.e. icon assets that are not the primary one) as well.

Do you know why CFBundleIconName worked in iOS 17? It feels magical that it worked before

Considering that iOS18 is still in beta and one of the tentpole features is how the system treats app icons, this is either a bug or a deliberate decision (perhaps to reduce bundle sizes - one can only guess). I would definitely open a radar for this though. Keep in mind that the API (CFBundleIconName) works exactly like it did before, it's the compiler that doesn't include the hires icon by default now.

Are you sure this does work for the alternative app icons? For me it does work with the main icon, but alternative app icons don't, even though ASSETCATALOG_COMPILER_INCLUDE_ALL_APPICON_ASSETS is set to YES.
I have tried with Xcode 16 Beta 5

If you mean including alt icons as free-standing files then no, this doesn't work, but the documentation states that either this flag or ASSETCATALOG_COMPILER_ALTERNATE_APPICON_NAMES (for more detailed control) is needed in order to create entries for CFBundleAlternateIcons in runtime.


If UIImage(named:) was called with the name of an app icon, it would previously return an undefined image of the icon set, without any masking or shadowing applied. On iOS 18, it now returns nil. To display an icon within the app itself, add the desired image to the asset catalog as an image set. (130491812) (FB14052579)

From iOS & iPadOS 18 Release Notes / UIKit / Deprecations.
